# Why am I getting NA's for sigma in this gamlss call?

Tags: r

The following question was asked by [Michael Barton](https://stats.stackexchange.com/users/5659/michael-barton) on Cross Validated and rejected because it was deemed to be a computer question.  Regardless, I personally think the question is interesting and am wondering if it can be answered here.

The original post is [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/297359/73007).

> I am fitting a gamlss model with the call:
>
> ```
> gamlss(formula = image_name + random(biological_source_name) - 1,
>        sigma.formula = biological_source_name - 1,
>        family = "NBI",
>        data = na.omit(data))
> ```
>
> After three iterations I get an error:
>
> ```
> GAMLSS-RS iteration 1: Global Deviance = 3814 
> GAMLSS-RS iteration 2: Global Deviance = 7760
> GAMLSS-RS iteration 3: Global Deviance = 7756
>
> In digamma(y + (1/sigma)) : NaNs produced
> In digamma(1/sigma) : NaNs produced
> In digamma(y + (1/sigma)) : NaNs produced
> In digamma(1/sigma) : NaNs produced
> Error in glim.fit(f = sigma.object, X = sigma.X, y = y, w = w, fv = sigma,  : 
>   NA's in the working vector or weights for parameter sigma
> ```
>
> This suggests to me that the estimated sigma for some of the
>   categorical predictors is going to 0. Would this be correct?
>
> Any suggestions on how to go about resolving this?

Comment: The question may be interesting and could be useful, but it does need an example, re [gung's comment](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/297359/how-to-resolve-nas-in-the-working-vector-or-weights-for-parameter-sigma-and?noredirect=1#comment565589_297359) [ps if you can add some example data it would definitely be helpful to have all your code here rather than some at another site.]

Comment: You merely need to indent the source code 4 spaces for each line so that SO can format it as code. You can do that by selecting the code, and clicking the code button in the editor (two curly braces `{ }` ). You don't need to apply PEP8 whitespace.

Comment: I have "imported" the original question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I contacted the authors regarding this. The issue is that a negative binomial is only able to model over dispersion, whereas my data contains both under- and over-dispersed output variables, between different dependent variable groups. This results in the error for the sigma going to 0.

> The problem could be that the data are underdispered. and sigma goes to zero and the derivatives produced NA’s.
>   Try to fit double Poisson DPO() in this specific data set.

As recommended by the one of the authors, a distribution such as double poisson allows for fitting this because the standard deviation can be modelled being both more or less than the mean. When using this distribution, this solved the above problem for me and I was able to fit a model.

```
gamlss(formula = metric ~ image_name + random(biological_source_name) - 1,
   sigma.formula = ~ biological_source_name - 1,
   family = "DPO",
   data = na.omit(data))
```

Note the use of `DPO` in the above example.